# pytz.timezone shows weird results for Asia/Calcutta?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Python datetime object show wrong timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410971/python-datetime-object-show-wrong-timezone-offset)

```
import pytz, datetime

 pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
```

prints the following:

```
< DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' HMT+5:53:00 STD >
```

Why it is not 05:30 hrs? I am in time zone America/Los_Angeles.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Time zones change over the years. According to http://www.prokerala.com/travel/timezones/Asia/Kolkata?mode=history the original offset for that zone was 5.88888888889 hours, or 5 hours 53 minutes. `pytz` will use the proper offset and nomenclature once you assign the zone to an actual date.

```
>>> tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' HMT+5:53:00 STD>
>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime(1901, 7, 10, 12, 0))
datetime.datetime(1901, 7, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' HMT+5:53:00 STD>)
>>> tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 10, 12, 0))
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 10, 12, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Calcutta' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
```

Comment: I believe crazier offsets were much closer to reality: Kolkata longitude: 88.369 deg. Now to get the time offset: (88.369/180)x12=5.89 which approx translates to 5 hrs and 53 minutes. Of course, reality must have made life difficult for everyone, hence rounded offsets now.

Comment: That's not a time offset that was actually enacted by law.  It's simply a reflection of [Local Mean Time (LMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) for the region covered by the zone.  You can see this in the tz source data [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017b/asia#L891).