# Weird timezone issue with pytz

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Hong_Kong' LMT+7:37:00 STD>
```

A seven hour and 37 minute offset? This is a little strange, does anyone experience the same issue?

In fact I'm getting different behavior between

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
hk = pytz.timezone('Asia/Hong_Kong')

dt1 = datetime(2012,1,1,tzinfo=hk)
dt2 = hk.localize(datetime(2012,1,1))
if dt1 > dt2:
   print "Why?"
```

Comment: what's the problem with being precise? [`The Hong Kong Time was first set to Local Mean Time (GMT+7:36:41) on 1 January 1885 at 13:00 by the then Royal Observatory Hong Kong`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Time#Time_standards)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442183/pytz-timezone-shows-weird-results-for-asia-calcutta/11442571#11442571

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python datetime object show wrong timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410971/python-datetime-object-show-wrong-timezone-offset)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Time zones and offsets change over the years. The default zone name and offset delivered when pytz creates a timezone object are the earliest ones available for that zone, and sometimes they can seem kind of strange. When you use `localize` to attach the zone to a date, the proper zone name and offset are substituted. Simply using the `datetime` constructor to attach the zone to the date doesn't allow it to adjust properly.

Answer (score 20):

Coming here nearly 10 years later, I think it's worth a note that we can now exclusively utilize the Python 3.9+ standard library to handle time zones, without a "localize trap".

Use the [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module to set and replace the tzinfo however you like, ex:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

hk = ZoneInfo('Asia/Hong_Kong')
print(repr(hk))
# zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Hong_Kong')

dt1 = datetime(2012,1,1,tzinfo=hk)
print(dt1)
# 2012-01-01 00:00:00+08:00

# set tz to a naive datetime object (pytz localize):
dt2 = datetime(2012,1,1).replace(tzinfo=hk)
print(dt2)
# 2012-01-01 00:00:00+08:00
```

- there is a [deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) for `pytz`

Alternatives, if you're not able to use `zoneinfo`:

- for Python < 3.9, there's [backports.zoneinfo](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/)
- you could also use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which follows the same semantics as `zoneinfo`

Note for `pandas` users:

- `pandas` (v1.4.1) is still using `pytz` internally, and seems to [have some trouble](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37654) with ZoneInfo timezone objects

Comment: I think the interface between `datetime` and `tzinfo` was extended to allow this to work. When `pytz` was created it was stuck working the way it did.

Comment: @MarkRansom right, I think I remember having looked into this in the context of another question. So it's not just an additional library and done, it's a bit of an evolution.

Answer (score 17):

While I'm sure historic changes in timezones are a factor, passing pytz timezone object to the DateTime constructor results in odd behavior even for timezones that have experienced no changes since their inception.

```
import datetime
import pytz 

dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo= pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

produces

```
2020-07-15 00:00:00-04:56
```

Creating the datetime object then localizing it produced expected results

```
import datetime
import pytz 

dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 15, 0, 0)
dt_local = timezone('US/Eastern').localize(dt)
```

produces

```
2020-07-15 00:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: Prior to November 1883, there weren't any standard time zones in the US; time was local: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_United_States#History.  I expect that the timezone database is returning New York time.

Comment: If you look at example data from the [Olson Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Example_zone_and_rule_lines) you can see that New York had an offset of `4:56:02` prior to `1883 November 18, 12:03:58`.  So it's incorrect that the New York time zone never changed.

Comment: I stand corrected. That would explain this behavior for datetimes in 1883, but not 2020

Comment: See my answer. The tzinfo object doesn't know what date you're going to use with it unless you use `localize`. For some reason pytz assumes 1883 is just as likely as 2020.

Comment: True but it is still reasonable to expect datetime to use the passed timezone object appropriately with the data parameters passed to its constructor.

Comment: No, because the `tzinfo` definition doesn't include a setup function that can be called from the constructor. It is forced to use it in its default state.

Comment: Take utmost with the DateTime constructor. Check this: with `t_now_secs = time.time()` doing `float(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t_now_secs, pytz.UTC).strftime('%s')) - t_now_secs` gives `-3600`. The local offset is dragged into this.

Comment: @YtsendeBoer yes the local offset is applied in your example, but it doesn't come from a `tzinfo` instance.

Comment: For us mere mortals this pytz behavior is not what one would expect. Wonder how many subtle timezone bugs exists out there due to this.