# when does `datetime.now(pytz_timezone)` fail?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, delorian

[`delorean` docs](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean) show this way to *get the current time in a given timezone* [using `datetime`](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/blob/2016040e07e63edfe3d565129049b1099d75be5f/README.rst#getting-started):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

EST = "US/Eastern"
UTC = "UTC"

d = datetime.utcnow()
utc = timezone(UTC)
est = timezone(EST)
d = utc.localize(d)
d = est.normalize(EST)
```

and compare it with the delorian-based code:

```
from delorean import Delorean

EST = "US/Eastern"

d = Delorean(timezone=EST)
```

[I believe](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/pull/46) the `datetime` example should be written as:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

eastern_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
d = datetime.now(eastern_timezone)
```

that is more concise.

Are there any cases when the last code example fails while the first one continues to work?

---

**Update:** [the current example:](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/blob/24065c7f6c96251cb6cf09436a76acf2c2d99022/README.rst)

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

d = datetime.utcnow()
d = pytz.utc.localize(d)

est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
d = est.normalize(d)
return d
```

that is still too verbose.

The question stills stands: [do you need the explicit round-trip via utc and `tz.normalize()` or can you use `datetime.now(tz)` instead?](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/pull/46)

Comment: His goal is to give an example on the project main page of how using a `Delorean` is cleaner than using `datetime` and `pytz`.  It's a bad example because it's incorrect code and can be handled better by your example, but your example doesn't meet the original goal.  Maybe propose a new example that shows a case where `localize` and `normalize` are actually necessary and how it's more easily handled with a `Delorean`?

Comment: I filed an [issue](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/issues/70) with delorean, so they created a [pull request](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/pull/71/files) that cleans up the first example.  (They also cleaned up the delorean example.)

Comment: @heenenee: my question is about `datetime.now(tz)`: whether you can always use it to return the current time in a given timezone instead of `est.normalize(utc.localize(datetime.uctnow()).astimezone(est))`.

Comment: @PatrickMaupin: [the merged example](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/blob/24065c7f6c96251cb6cf09436a76acf2c2d99022/README.rst) is still too verbose. The question stills stands: do you need the explicit round-trip via utc and `tz.normalize()` or  can you just use `datetime.now(tz)` as shown in the question. I think `datetime.now(tz)` is enough but [delorian's author disagrees](https://github.com/myusuf3/delorean/pull/46)

Comment: I don't disagree, but the first example bothered me because it didn't actually work as coded (as the answer below notes).  Thought it was better to get an agreed-upon target for the disagreement, if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When does `datetime.now(pytz_timezone)` fail?

As far as I can tell, there are no scenarios where it could fail.  `datetime.now` invokes the `fromutc` function on the `tzinfo` instance passed in the parameter.  All conversions from UTC to local time are unambiguous, so there are no opportunities for failure.

Also, the original code does not even work.

```
d = est.normalize(EST)
```

This would appear to pass a string as the only parameter to `normalize`, which is intended to take a `datetime`.  This gives:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

I believe they meant to write:

```
d = est.normalize(d.astimezone(est))
```

That said, I don't think the verbosity of their code adds much value.  As you noted, it's just as easy to do this in a single step:

```
d = datetime.now(est)
```

Looking at the [cpython source code for `datetime.now`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f18916ecc6ca733478257e1cc0793386eed9a4c9/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L4157), I can see that when a `tzinfo` object is provided, it calls the `fromutc` method on that object.

```c
if (self != NULL && tz != Py_None) {
    /* Convert UTC to tzinfo's zone. */
    PyObject *temp = self;

    self = _PyObject_CallMethodId(tz, &PyId_fromutc, "O", self);
    Py_DECREF(temp);
}
```

Then, in the pytz source, I see that the `fromutc` method is implemented differently depending on whether the zone is `pytz.UTC`, or an instance of `StaticTzInfo`, or `DstTzInfo`.  In all three cases, the transformation from the input UTC value to the target time zone is unambiguous.  Here is the `DstTzInfo` implementation, which is the more complex of the three:

```
def fromutc(self, dt):
    '''See datetime.tzinfo.fromutc'''
    if (dt.tzinfo is not None
        and getattr(dt.tzinfo, '_tzinfos', None) is not self._tzinfos):
        raise ValueError('fromutc: dt.tzinfo is not self')
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)
    idx = max(0, bisect_right(self._utc_transition_times, dt) - 1)
    inf = self._transition_info[idx]
    return (dt + inf[0]).replace(tzinfo=self._tzinfos[inf])
```

This would appear to find the transition from `_utc_transition_times` of the time zone, then apply it to the returned `datetime`.  There are no ambiguities in this direction, so the results will be equivalent.

Also worth noting, in [the `datetime` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) it says that `datetime.now` is equivalent to calling:

```
tz.fromutc(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz))
```

Given the source of `fromutc` in pytz I showed earlier, I'm not sure that this is any different than just:

```
tz.fromutc(datetime.utcnow())
```

But in either case, I don't think `localize` and `normalize` are necessary.