# Why 1 hour wrong?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, python-babel

The time is 15:0x in Stockholm (Europe). But I'm getting the localized time 1 hour wrong:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 17, 15, 2, 42, 633000)
>>> babel.dates.format_datetime(datetime.datetime.now(), 'full', tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm'),locale='en')
u'Thursday, December 17, 2015 at 4:02:49 PM Central European Standard Time'
>>>
```

What is the mistake?

Comment: Why the downvote? I really tried to get the time right.

Comment: timezone, obviously... pretty much anytime you get an expected date off by exactly 1 hour (or multiple thereof), it's going to be timezone related.

Comment: @MarcB Yes and how? I was explicitly setting the timezone to `Europe/ Stockholm`.

Comment: I am pretty sure `datetime.now()` already includes local time. try `datetime.utcnow()` which defaults to a timezone of `None` https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now

Comment: but you didn't tell the system what timezone your input date is in, so it's assuming something "wrong". you specified a TZ for the output only.

Comment: @Busturdust that's it! This works: `babel.dates.format_datetime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), 'full', tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm'),locale='en')`

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify timezone in your datetime.now: `datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm'))`

Comment: another solution could have been to pass an explicit timezoe to the dateime.now() call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to have been the baked in local time of the `datetime.datetime.now()` call. As mentioned in the comments, use `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` for a timezone agnostic `coordinated universal time`, or input the desired timezone info into the datetime call  `datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm'))`

Comment: This is the solution I use now.

Comment: and yet, somehow downvoted :), enjoy, happy programming

Comment: @Busturdust great answer! how do I use the second method with my datetime variable instead of datetime.now?

Comment: if you have a variable of type datetime you should just be able to do variable.now

Answer (score 5):

Explicit is better than implicit. Set the timezone for `now`:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm'))
```

Comment: Thank you! It's good that we can accomplish it. The output is pretty neat.

Comment: @Programmer400: the advantage is that `.now(tz)` works even during DST transitions when the local time may be ambiguous. If you need to make timezone-aware an existing naive datetime object then use `tz.localize(dt, is_dst=None)`.

Comment: [`.now(tz)` always works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31886808/4279). `datetime(tzinfo=tz)` is WRONG unless `tz` is a fixed-offset timezone.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastion: Thanks for the info.