# Python. How to create a local datetime with datetime.today()

Tags: python, datetime

The server sends a string that I `striptime` and keep in a variable called here `time_from_frontend` and then add a tzinfo like this:

```
import pytz

my_timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Guayaquil")

A = time_from_frontend.replace(tzinfo=my_timezone)
print A
print A.tzinfo

B = (datetime.datetime.today()).replace(tzinfo=my_timezone)
print B
print B.tzinfo

print B - A
```

Why do I get a huge difference between A and B? Here is what the terminal prints:

```
2016-02-11 20:00:00-05:19
America/Guayaquil
2016-02-12 01:08:35.478507-05:19
America/Guayaquil
5:08:35.478507
```

The frontend is sending me the actual time, when I do `datetime.today()` and then specify the timezone, I thought I was gonna get a tiny difference between the A time and the B time (i.e microseconds), but I get 5 hours. which is the timezone difference ("America/Guayaquil" is GMT-5).

I kind of understand the error. But how can I solve it? is there a way to create a `datetime.today()` object that corresponds to the local time?

Comment: You seem to be looking for [pytz - World Timezone Definitions for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/python-how-to-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-that-is-timezone-aware)

Comment: Check this out, http://tommikaikkonen.github.io/timezones, maybe this will help you

Comment: related: [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `datetime` from your frontend is in UTC.  Doing a replace doesn't actually convert the datetime.  It uses the data/hour/etc. and just uses a new timezone.

When you call `datetime.today()`, you create a *naive* datetime without any timezone info.  When you do a `replace` on that, it's not actually doing a conversion either, it's just assuming the date you gave it is already in the timezone you provided, the same as the replace you did on the server time.

To actually *convert* datetimes to another timezone, you need to use [`astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone).  If the datetime from the server is also *naive* and doesn't specify a timezone, `astimezone` will error.  To fix that. add a timezone of `UTC` first.

```
time_from_frontend = time_from_frontend.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
converted_server_time = time_from_frontend.astimezone(my_timezone)
```

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.today()` already returns the local datetime (the result is almost the same as `datetime.now()`). Both return the local time as naive datetime objects (avoid them unless you want to display them immediately).

The correct way to get the current time in a given timezone is to use [`datetime.now(tz)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31886808/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_time = datetime.now(tzlocal.get_localzone())
```

It works even during DST transitions when the local time may be ambiguous (using a naive `datetime.today()` may fail in this case).

`tzlocal` returns a `pytz` tzinfo object and therefore it handles timezones that might have had a different UTC offset in the past (non-pytz code may fail in this case).

---

There are several issues in your code:

- [don't use `naive_dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)` where `tz` has a non-fixed utc offset. Use `tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace#comment41069172_1379874)
- the time difference in your question indicates that `time_from_frontend` might be in UTC (not your local timezone) as [@Brendan Abel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35353430/4279). To compare it with the current time, you could use `datetime.utcnow()` if `time_from_frontend` is a naive datetime object that represents UTC time:

  ```
  time_diff = datetime.utcnow() - time_from_frontend
  ```

  To get timezone-aware datetime, you can [use `.replace()` with UTC timezone (the utc offset is fixed -- it is always zero),](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32904812/4279) :

  ```
  frontend_time = time_from_frontend.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
  ```

  If both datetime objects are timezone-aware then the subtraction works too:

  ```
  time_diff = local_time - frontend_time
  ```

See also:

- [How to get current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611645/4279)
- [Python: How to get a value of datetime.today() that is “timezone aware”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25421145/4279)