# Why does it make a difference if I add 1 hour to the UTC time and localize or 1 hour to the local time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta, pytz

### Example Code

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pytz

t11 = datetime(1918, 4, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
t12 = t11 + timedelta(hours=1)

t2 = datetime(1918, 4, 15, 1, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))

print(t12)
print(t2)
```

### Observed

```
1918-04-15 02:00:00+01:00
1918-04-15 03:00:00+02:00
```

### Expected

I expected both to be what I see for `t2`. The crucial difference is `t2.hour` vs `t12.hour`. For a timezone-aware datetime object, I expected the hour to be the local hour.

### Question

How can I change this behaviour? What is the reason for having it like this?

Comment: Again, this isn't about the library, it's about German time; that's when the clocks changed: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany?year=1918. You'd see different behaviour if you weren't moving over a change between winter/summer time.

Comment: Sure. This is exactly why I chose this time.

Comment: Then why don't you mention that in the question? And why 1918; doesn't it happen with this year's change? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185504/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it is clear that I didn't accidentally choose the hour at which DST kicks in. (1918 because I was experimenting with old changes in timezones.  Originally, I wanted to see if pytz knows about rather old changes. See [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerzeit#Deutschland).

Answer (score -1):

I will not accept the following, because it only explains how to do it right. It doesn't explain why adding timedelta doesn't work the expected way in the first place.

### How to fix it

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185504/3001761) suggests to take the following approach:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pytz

# Timezone-aware object to start with
t11 = datetime(1918, 4, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))

# Extract timezone information
tzinfo = t11.tzinfo

# Convert to UTC, add timedelta, convert to local timezone
t13 = (t11.astimezone(pytz.timezone('utc')) + timedelta(hours=1)).astimezone(tzinfo)
```

Another way to do it:

```
t14 = t11 + timedelta(hours=1)  # Invalid timezone!
t14 = t14.astimezone(pytz.utc).astimezone(t14.tzinfo)  # Fix the timezone
```

Now I have:

```
t11: 1918-04-15 01:00:00+01:00
t13: 1918-04-15 03:00:00+02:00  # one hour more and +1h because of DST
```

### Pendulum

The package [`pendulum`](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum) is another way to fix it:

```
from pendulum import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pytz

t11 = datetime(1918, 4, 15, 0, 0).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
t12 = t11 + timedelta(hours=1)

t2 = datetime(1918, 4, 15, 1, 0).astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
```

gives:

```
t11: 1918-04-15T01:00:00+01:00
t12: 1918-04-15T03:00:00+02:00
t2 : 1918-04-15T03:00:00+02:00
```