# How to convert datetime from string to utc aware version

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, pytz, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a datetime, that originates from a string:

```
myString = '20200505:1715'
datetime.datetime.strptime(myString, "%Y%m%d:%H%M")
# datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 5, 17, 15)
```

This datetime happens in `'EST'`.

Following the advice, that one should operate internally only with `UTC` datetimes, I would like to convert it accordingly (see: [Daylight savings time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203676/daylight-savings-time-in-python) ).

What is the proper way of doing this?

I know that for `now()` this should be done in the following way, as depicted in [Daylight savings time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203676/daylight-savings-time-in-python), but I wonder how this would look like for an arbitrary parsed datetime?

```
import pytz
import datetime

utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
now = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770297/convert-utc-datetime-string-to-local-datetime -- Possible answer

Comment: `strptime` gives you a naïve datetime object. Make that *aware* as EST time, then convert its timezone.