# python: Incorrect(?) time difference between `datetime` objects spanning a daylight saving time change

Tags: python, datetime, dst

---

(edited to add)

**PROLOG:** Today I became aware of the concept of "wall time".  I will always and forever consider it harmful.

---

I have two `datetimes`, one representing a certain time-of-day just before a time change, and the other representing the same time-of-day one calendar day after the the first `datetime`.  I would expect the time difference between these two objects to not be exactly one day, but that's what I see (with python3.8, which is all I have to work with).

Taking the difference of the *timestamps* associated with the `datetimes` returns exactly what I would expect to see.  Taking the difference of `datetime` objects when they span a time change looks flat-out wrong to me.

Is this expected behavior?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import gettz # pip install dateutil

def iso(dt):
    return dt.strftime('%FT%T%z')

# Daylight saving time begins at 2 a.m. local time on Sunday, March 10, 2024
us_central = gettz('US/Central')
before = datetime(2024, 3,  9, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central)
after  = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central)

print()
print(f'before time change: {iso(before)}')
print(f' after time change: {iso(after)}')

naive = after - before
by_timestamps = timedelta(seconds = after.timestamp() - before.timestamp())
difference_difference = naive.total_seconds() - by_timestamps.total_seconds()

print()
print('Differences:')
print(f'        naive: {repr(naive)}')
print(f'by timestamps: {repr(by_timestamps)}')
print(f'        error: {difference_difference}s')
```

Output (python3.8)

```
before time change: 2024-03-09T15:22:01-0600
 after time change: 2024-03-10T15:22:01-0500

Differences:
        naive: datetime.timedelta(days=1)
by timestamps: datetime.timedelta(seconds=82800)
        error: 3600.0s
```

---

(Edited to add)

This is so counterintuitive to me. "Wall time" is very strange.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import gettz # pip install dateutil

# Daylight saving time begins at 2 a.m. local time on Sunday, March 10, 2024
us_central = gettz('US/Central')
before = datetime(2024, 3,  9, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central)
after  = datetime(2024, 3, 10, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central)

print(repr((before + timedelta(days=1)) - after))
print(repr((before + timedelta(seconds=86400)) - after))

# what I think the above should do...
print(repr(datetime.fromtimestamp(before.timestamp() + 86400, tz=before.tzinfo) - after))
```

Output (python3.8)

```
datetime.timedelta(0)
datetime.timedelta(0)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

Comment: Have you read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203676/daylight-savings-time-in-python)?

Comment: @joe Thanks for the pointer.  It's pretty obvious that such manipulations should be done with normalized scalar timestamps, but I don't understand why those details aren't buried in the `datetime` library.  Seems very broken to me.

Comment: Do time math in UTC otherwise "wall time" is used.

Comment: What even is "wall time"?  I'll just use timestamps.

Comment: Timestamps are always in UTC, so if you don't have a correct time zone attached to your datetime they'll be incorrect.

Comment: Wall time is not harmful, because there are circumstances where you need it.  There are events you want to track that will always occur the same time of day whether daylight savings is in effect or not.  It's merely inconvenient.

Comment: @MarkRansom Timestamps have no timezone. Also, why would anyone create `datetime` objects without timezones?

Comment: @MarkRansom `datetime` objects represent moments in time.  It intuitively follows that the actual timespan between those moments would simply be the difference between `datetime` objects.  As I mentioned elsewhere, I'll just convert to timestamps for manipulations, and then convert results back to `datetime` objects. This whole situation blows my mind.  I'm used to the consistent semantics of `std::chrono`

Comment: `std::chrono` was invented long after Python's `datetime`.  They had the benefit of seeing the way everybody else dealt with the problems, and they didn't need to provide 20 years of backward compatibility.

Comment: A question for you: which is more useful, having the difference in days be consistent, or having the difference in seconds be consistent?  You can't have both since a day isn't a consistent number of seconds.  P.S. I'm glad you found a solution that works for you.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that the difference between two `datetime` objects would be the _actual_ elapsed time between the timepoints.  I mean, why would it be anything different than that?

Comment: @MarkRansom as to usefulness -- for me consistency _of the actual time and duration_ is much more useful than the library "trying to be helpful".  For my work, both time-of-day values and duration values are equally important.  So to account for dst time changes, I have would to ether adjust the day value myself (if the library didn't do that), or (as `datetime` is currently written) I would have to adjust the duration value myself, which is INSANE.

Comment: @smcdow, I think the answer to your question "why would it be anything different than that?" is that someone might want to write a program in which they add a certain number of days and expect the time of day not to change.  It sounds to me like those people can use datetime time deltas, but if someone wants the exact seconds elapsed, they should use timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

Do time difference calculations in UTC otherwise "wall" time is used.  Below fixes your code, and has an example of advancing by 15-minute increments over the end of daylight savings time (Nov 3, 2024, 2am rolls back to 1am).  It also uses the newer built-in [`zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module (available since Python 3.9) which uses either the system time zone information or falls back to the 3rd party [`tzdata`](https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/) module for the latest time zone information:

```py
# May need "pip install -U tzdata" on some OSes for latest time zone info.
import datetime as dt
import zoneinfo as zi

# Daylight saving time begins at 2 a.m. local time on Sunday, March 10, 2024
us_central = zi.ZoneInfo('US/Central')

# Compute times as a local time zone but convert to UTC.
before = dt.datetime(2024, 3,  9, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central).astimezone(dt.timezone.utc)
after  = dt.datetime(2024, 3, 10, 15, 22, 1, tzinfo=us_central).astimezone(dt.timezone.utc)

# Display in preferred time zone
print()
print(f'before time change: {before.astimezone(us_central)}')
print(f' after time change: {after.astimezone(us_central)}')

naive = after - before
by_timestamps = dt.timedelta(seconds = after.timestamp() - before.timestamp())
difference_difference = naive.total_seconds() - by_timestamps.total_seconds()

print()
print('Differences:')
print(f'        naive: {repr(naive)}')
print(f'by timestamps: {repr(by_timestamps)}')
print(f'        error: {difference_difference}s')

current = dt.datetime(2024, 11, 3, 1, tzinfo=us_central).astimezone(dt.timezone.utc)
for minutes in range(12):
    print(current.astimezone(us_central))
    current += dt.timedelta(seconds=15 * 60)
```

Output (with notations):

```
before time change: 2024-03-09 15:22:01-06:00
 after time change: 2024-03-10 15:22:01-05:00

Differences:
        naive: datetime.timedelta(seconds=82800)
by timestamps: datetime.timedelta(seconds=82800)
        error: 0.0s
2024-11-03 01:00:00-05:00
2024-11-03 01:15:00-05:00
2024-11-03 01:30:00-05:00
2024-11-03 01:45:00-05:00
2024-11-03 01:00:00-06:00
2024-11-03 01:15:00-06:00
2024-11-03 01:30:00-06:00
2024-11-03 01:45:00-06:00
2024-11-03 02:00:00-06:00
2024-11-03 02:15:00-06:00
2024-11-03 02:30:00-06:00
2024-11-03 02:45:00-06:00
```

Also note that [`datetime.datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) and [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) are not recommended to be used due to returning *naive* timestamps that use local system time (and therefore "wall" time) for math.  They have also been deprecated in Python 3.12.

Comment: It's unfortunate that they waited so long to give us `zoneinfo`.  Until recently I too was stuck on Python 3.8 and couldn't take advantage.

Answer (score 1):

From [cpython's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4a2e8a2c5188c3288d57b80852e92c83f46f6f3/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L2235) (the pure Python fallback module, though I expect the results to be equivalent to the C code):

```
class datetime:
    ...
    def __sub__(self, other):
        "Subtract two datetimes, or a datetime and a timedelta."
        if not isinstance(other, datetime):
            if isinstance(other, timedelta):
                return self + -other
            return NotImplemented

        days1 = self.toordinal()
        days2 = other.toordinal()
        secs1 = self._second + self._minute * 60 + self._hour * 3600
        secs2 = other._second + other._minute * 60 + other._hour * 3600
        base = timedelta(days1 - days2,
                         secs1 - secs2,
                         self._microsecond - other._microsecond)
        if self._tzinfo is other._tzinfo:
            return base
        myoff = self.utcoffset()
        otoff = other.utcoffset()
        if myoff == otoff:
            return base
        if myoff is None or otoff is None:
            raise TypeError("cannot mix naive and timezone-aware time")
        return base + otoff - myoff
```

**Note that there's no code to account for daylight saving time changes.**

Therefore I'd suggest localizing your datetime objects to UTC before performing any timedelta computation.

And if your code needs to be accurate to the second, note that Python also ignores leap seconds, and even Unix time (generated by `.timestamp()`) makes bad choices. Subtracting two Unix timestamps around a leap second will be off by one, because even though the timestamps *look* independent of calendar, they were patched for backwards compatibility with code that assumed a fixed amount of seconds per day.

Comment: I think the intention was that `utcoffset` would deliver different results based on the `tzinfo` component, because `tzinfo` would know if you were on DST or not.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh, definitely. I consider this a bad bug from Python's part. Unfortunately it probably cannot be fixed without breaking backwards compatibility...

Comment: I think actually it's a non-problem if you use `zoneinfo`, because they enhanced the interfaces to allow it to work smarter.

Comment: @BoppreH This blows my mind.  I mean, even plain old `mktime` figures out whether the time point in question falls in DST or not.  Seems like it would have been trivial to include DST awareness in the `datetime` library.