# How to mock python's datetime.now() in a class method for unit testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I'm trying to write tests for a class that has methods like:

```
import datetime
import pytz

class MyClass:
    def get_now(self, timezone):
        return datetime.datetime.now(timezone)

    def do_many_things(self, tz_string='Europe/London'):
        tz = pytz.timezone(tz_string)
        localtime_now = self.get_now(tz)
        ...
        return things
```

I want to test it, and to do so I need to make sure that the `datetime.datetime.now()` call returns something predictable.

I've been reading lots of examples of using [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) in tests, but haven't found anything quite like what I need, and I can't work out how to use it in my tests.

I separated the `get_now()` method out in case it's easier to mock that, instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`, but I'm still stumped. Any thoughts on how to write UnitTests for this using Mock? (This is all in Django, fwiw; I'm not sure if this makes a difference in this case.)

Comment: Just FYI, never use a pytz timezone in the datetime constructor. Use `localize` instead.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So instead of `datetime.datetime.now(timezone)` I should do `timezone.localize(datetime.datetime.now())`? Any particular reason it's better?

Comment: Sometimes assigning the timezone directly doesn't work properly. For one example see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808845/pytz-america-edmon-offset-wrong

Comment: Although, `localize()` is only used for naive `datetimes`. So if `now()` is 2012-10-26 15:00:00 (with no timezone) then it simply applies the specified timezone to it; it doesn't convert the time. As I want to get the actual time in a timezone, I think I need to do: `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).astimezone(timezone)`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) :

```
from freezegun import freeze_time

def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.now() != datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)
    with freeze_time("2012-01-14"):
        assert datetime.datetime.now() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)
    assert datetime.datetime.now() != datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)
```

It basically mocks `datetime` module calls.

Comment: Thanks, It works!
However the first assertion did not because the month token was not accepted in this format: `01` but `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14)` works.

Comment: freezegun is slow, especially if you test logic with multiple calls to datetime.now()

Answer (score 35):

You'd create a function that returns a specific datetime, localized to the timezone passed in:

```
import mock

def mocked_get_now(timezone):
    dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10)
    return timezone.localize(dt)

@mock.patch('path.to.your.models.MyClass.get_now', side_effect=mocked_get_now)
def your_test(self, mock_obj):
    # Within this test, `MyClass.get_now()` is a mock that'll return a predictable
    # timezone-aware datetime object, set to 2012-01-01 10:10:10.
```

That way you can test if the resulting timezone-aware datetime is correctly being handled;  results elsewhere should show the correct timezone but will have a predictable date and time.

You use the `mocked_get_now` function as a side-effect when mocking `get_now`; whenever code calls `get_now` the call is recorded by `mock`, *and* `mocked_get_now` is called, and it's return value used as the value returned to the caller of `get_now`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can't able to import `mock`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `mock` is an add-on package, install it with pip. With Python 3 it is included as `unittest.mock`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the most elegant way to do this IMO:

```
import datetime
from unittest import mock

test_now = datetime.datetime(1856, 7, 10)
with mock.patch('datetime.datetime', wraps=datetime.datetime) as dt:
    print(dt.now()) # calls the real thing
    dt.now.return_value = test_now
    print(dt.now()) # calls the mocked value
```

The advantages here is that you needn't patch the datetime module via the tested module's local attribute, it supports calling unmocked methods, and it doesn't require any external imports.

Comment: when I add `print(datetime.now())` I still get the actual datetime. Not the mocked one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `date`, but the same idea should work for `datetime`:

```
class SpoofDate(date):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return date.__new__(date, *args, **kwargs)
```

...

```
from mock import patch

@patch('some.module.date', SpoofDate)
def testSomething(self):
    SpoofDate.today = classmethod(lambda cls : date(2012, 9, 24))
```

Where `some.module` imports `date`.  Patch is replacing the imported `date` with `SpoofDate`, which you can then redefine to do whatever you want.

Comment: @FearlessFuture did you just replace `date` with `datetime`? Can you write the implementation in `datetime`.

Comment: @zakiakhmad, below is an example of what I did:
    class StubDate(datetime.datetime):
        pass
    
    @mock.patch("friend.datetime.datetime", StubDate)
    def test_generate_date(self):
    
        # Make datetime.datetime.now return a fixed value
        StubDate.now = classmethod(lambda cls: datetime.datetime(2015, 03, 11, 11, 01))
        self.assertEqual(
            self.friend_obj.generate_date(input), datetime.datetime(2015, 03, 11, 11, 01))
    
    > Blockquote

Comment: @FearlessFuture thanks a lot! I wrote the gist here for a better readability. https://gist.github.com/za/2a217c47582737f88259

Answer (score 3):

Having asked this question originally...

As @Jocelyn delalande suggested, I've been happily using [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) for years now.

Another option is [python-libfaketime](https://github.com/simon-weber/python-libfaketime/), which can be much faster than freezegun, but doesn't work on Windows and sounds a bit fiddly.

A newer option is [time-machine](https://github.com/adamchainz/time-machine), introduced in [this blog post](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/06/03/introducing-time-machine/) that compares the three options.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the helpers from the 'testfixtures' package to mock out the datetime class you're calling now() on:

http://packages.python.org/testfixtures/datetime.html#datetimes

That way, you can test all the cases you have, all the time.

Comment: Thank you, works much better and simpler than any other solutions

Answer (score 2):

> Using patch of unittest.mock

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('MyClass.datetime')
def test_foo(self, mock_datetime):
    mock_datetime.datetime.now.return_value = datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 7) #SOME_MOCKED_DATE
```

Note that **we're overriding datetime module that is imported only in our class**

The class for which we are writing the test:

```
import datetime

class MyClass:
    def foo():
       localtime_now = datetime.datetime.now(timezone)
```

We need not have to separate it as get_now() method just to make it easier to mock.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install anything this is the simplest way. Simply use,
Mock class -

```
class NewDt(datetime.date):
    @classmethod
     def now(cls):
           return datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-07-10 05:20:20', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

And use this patch before mock function

```
 @mock.patch('module path', NewDt)
```