# Monkey patch datetime.now() in an entire Django app with unittest.mock

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, datetime, mocking

I have a Django project with this file structure:

```
.
├── app
│  ├── __init__.py
│  ├── admin.py
│  ├── apps.py
│  ├── child_app
│  │  └── my_calendar.py
│  ├── migrations
│  ├── models.py
│  ├── tests.py
│  └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── mock_django
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── asgi.py
   ├── settings.py
   ├── urls.py
   └── wsgi.py
```

In my `views.py`, I have a call to `datetime.now()`:

```py
from datetime import datetime


def time_now():
    return datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

And in `child_app/my_calendar.py`, I have another call to `datetime.now()`:

```py
from datetime import datetime


def another_method():
    return datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

This is a simple example, but in real life this Django app has a lot of child apps with many calls to `datetime.now()`, and I'm trying to write a test to mock all of them. Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55187924/6282576), I can use this to mock `datetime.now()` in a module:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest import mock
from datetime import datetime
from views import time_now


class TestApp(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("views.datetime", wraps=datetime)
    def test_datetime_now(self, views_datetime):
        views_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)

        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
```

This test passes, and I can do the same for the other module:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest import mock
from datetime import datetime
from views import time_now
from child_app.my_calendar import another_method


class TestApp(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("views.datetime", wraps=datetime)
    @mock.patch("child_app.my_calendar.datetime", wraps=datetime)
    def test_datetime_now(self, my_calendar_datetime, views_datetime):
        my_calendar_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)
        views_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)

        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
        self.assertEqual(another_method(), "2022-09-10 14")
```

This test passes as well. Now I have a lot more modules and it's a pain, and ultimately infeasible, to write a separate decorator for each and every one of them. **How can I monkey patch every `datetime.now()` in an entire Django app (here `app`) in a DRY manner?** I can't do this:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest import mock
from datetime import datetime
from views import time_now
from child_app.my_calendar import another_method


class TestApp(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("app.datetime", wraps=datetime)
    def test_datetime_now(self, mock_datetime):
        mock_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)

        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
        self.assertEqual(another_method(), "2022-09-10 14")
```

Because:

```py
AttributeError: <module 'app' from 'mock_django/app/__init__.py'> does
not have the attribute 'datetime'
```

Now I can't change the actual code and I can only change the tests, but even if I add `from datetime import datetime` to `mock_django/app/__init__.py`, the tests will fail.

I tried to use [`mock.patch.object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object):

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest import mock
from datetime import datetime
from views import time_now
from child_app.my_calendar import another_method


class TestApp(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.object(datetime, 'now')
    def test_datetime_now(self, mock_datetime):
        mock_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)

        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
        self.assertEqual(another_method(), "2022-09-10 14")
```

But this gives another error:

```py
TypeError: cannot set 'now' attribute of immutable type 'datetime.datetime'
```

I can achieve the results I want using [`time_machine`](https://github.com/adamchainz/time-machine):

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from datetime import datetime
from views import time_now
from child_app.my_calendar import another_method
import time_machine


@time_machine.travel(datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14))
class TestApp(TestCase):
    def test_datetime_now(self):
        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
        self.assertEqual(another_method(), "2022-09-10 14")
```

But I'm wondering if I can do exactly this with `unittest.mock`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock python's datetime.now() in a class method for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073281/how-to-mock-pythons-datetime-now-in-a-class-method-for-unit-testing)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I can't find an answer there that solves this specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pkgutil.walk_packages` to find the submodules and then recursively patch them:

```py
import contextlib
import importlib
import pkgutil
from unittest.mock import DEFAULT, MagicMock, patch


def patch_in_app(app, *, attribute, wraps):
    module = importlib.import_module(app)
    targets = [
        f"{name}.{attribute}"
        for _, name, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(module.__path__, prefix=f"{app}.")
        if hasattr(importlib.import_module(name), attribute)
    ]

    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _func(*args):
            with patch_all(*targets, new=MagicMock(wraps=wraps)) as mock:
                return func(*args, mock)
        return _func

    return decorator


@contextlib.contextmanager
def patch_all(target, *targets, new=DEFAULT):
    with patch(target, new=new) as mock:
        if targets:
            with patch_all(*targets, new=mock):
                yield mock
        else:
            yield mock
```

Usage:

```py
class TestApp(TestCase):
    # @mock.patch("app.views.datetime", wraps=datetime)                  # Change these
    # @mock.patch("app.child_app.my_calendar.datetime", wraps=datetime)  #
    @patch_in_app("app", attribute="datetime", wraps=datetime)           # to this
    def test_datetime_now(self, mock_datetime):
        mock_datetime.now.return_value = datetime(2022, 9, 10, 14)

        self.assertEqual(time_now(), "2022-09-10 14")
        self.assertEqual(another_method(), "2022-09-10 14")
```