# Pandas timestamp and python datetime interpret timezone differently

Tags: pandas, datetime

I don't understand why `a` isn't the same as `b`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

here = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')

a = pd.Timestamp('2018-4-9', tz=here).to_pydatetime() 
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
b = datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, tzinfo=here)
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' LMT+0:20:00 STD>)

print(b-a)
# returns 01:40:00
```

Comment: What does `b-a` return?

Comment: b-a returns 1:40:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45755336/why-does-creating-a-datetime-with-a-tzinfo-from-pytz-show-a-weird-time-offset) I learned that `tzinfo` doesn't work well for some timezones and that could be the reason for the wrong result.
[pytz doc](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime
>   constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

The solution is to use `localize` or `astimezone`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

here = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')

a = pd.Timestamp('2018-4-9', tz=here).to_pydatetime() 
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
b = here.localize(datetime(2018, 4, 9))
# datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

print(b-a)
# returns 00:00:00
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks, learned something new about time and timezones in python.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a and b,

```
a
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

verus

```
b
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' LMT+0:20:00 STD>)
```

CEST European Central Summer Time

vs

LMT Local Mean Time

Comment: It seems that here CEST is the same as LMT time, but pandas and python interpret the same time zone differently?