# Removing offset and converting datetime object to UTC in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to convert a timezone aware datetime to UTC, but **without carrying an offset**:

I receive some data to create a start date for an event: year, month, day, hours, minutes

I have a `venue` object and use its longitude and latitude to obtain the venue timezone like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

tf = TimezoneFinder()
tz_str = tf.timezone_at(lng=venue.longitude, lat=venue.latitude)
```

For instance `tz_str` can take the value `'Asia/Tokyo'`

I then create a timezone aware datetime object:

```
start_date = datetime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone(tz_str))
```

this will have the value `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' LMT+9:19:00 STD>)`

I would like to convert it to UTC before storing to the DB, but I don't want the offset.

If I simply convert to UTC, it will keep the offset which I don't want:

```
utc_start_date = start_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

this will take the following value `datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 23, 41, tzinfo=<UTC>)`, which is 19 minutes off.

How can I remove the offset?

Comment: I found that  one option is to create an non-aware datetime object and then localize it:
`start_date = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo').localize(
    datetime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0)
)`

this will have value `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 9, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>). Note that the 19 in offset has disappeared

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473721/weird-timezone-issue-with-pytz)