# Incorrect datetime conversion from America/New_York time to UTC and back to America/New_York

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I am trying to convert time from America/New York to UTC and then converting it back to the New York time. But I get different results while doing with this with `pytz`.

I am doing this:

```py
new_date = parser.parse("May 4, 2021")
new_date = new_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
date = new_date.astimezone(pytz.timezone("UTC"))
```

Output:

```py
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 4, 4, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

When I try to reconvert it back to the
New York time I get this:

```
date.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
```

I get:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 4, 0, 56, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

My Question is why there is 56 minute difference and what can be done to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 56 min difference originates from the fact that the first entry in the database that `pytz` accesses, refers to LMT (local mean time):

```
import pytz
t = pytz.timezone("America/New_York")
print(repr(t))
# <DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>
```

You can read more in P. Ganssle's [Fastest Footgun](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html) blog post or in [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418) here on SO.

**tl;dr - Never `replace` a tzinfo with a timezone object from `pytz`!** Use `localize` (or `astimezone`) instead, to adjust the timezone to the year of the datetime object.

***...But:*** since you use `dateutil` already, why don't you use it here as well:

```
import dateutil

new_date = dateutil.parser.parse("May 4, 2021")
# you can safely replace with dateutil's tz objects:
new_date = new_date.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz("America/New_York"))
date = new_date.astimezone(dateutil.tz.UTC)   

# date
# datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 4, 4, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())

date = date.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz("America/New_York"))
# date
# datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzfile('US/Eastern'))
print(date)
# 2021-05-04 00:00:00-04:00
```

Comment: yeah, I already. Resolved the issue with the same solution. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -1):

The code is functioning as intended.

There is not a 56 minutes difference. There is a 4 hour difference.

> datetime.datetime( 
> 2021, // yyyy 
> 5,    // mm 
> 4,    // dd 
> 4,    // hh -- This is hours
> 56,   // mi  
> tzinfo=)

4 hours also happens to be the hours by which UTC is ahead of US Eastern Time. When it is 00:56 Hrs in New York, in UTC time it will be 04:56 Hrs.

Comment: when I convert a naive time to New York and then to UTC, it should get the same from UTC when I convert it backward. but I am not getting it back same.

Comment: Please print the raw date in US format, TZ converted date (UTC) and TZ converted back (US).

Comment: You can see my outputs, are they varying Machine to Machine?

Comment: You have only two. Print the raw datetime also.

Comment: @vvgiri: check the blog post I linked in my answer to find out more about the 56 min difference (which happens to be there...)

Comment: @vvg the time started out with `minutes=0` and ended up with `minutes=56`.  That is definitely not "as intended".  I think you have misread the question.