# Conversion between two time zones in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to convert time in two time zones in Python, and I have following problem.

The code

```
import pytz
import datetime

chicago_timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")
polish_time_zone = pytz.timezone("Europe/Warsaw")

chicago_time = datetime.datetime(2020,6,25,8,0,0,0,chicago_timezone)
print(chicago_time)

polish_time = chicago_time.astimezone(polish_time_zone)
print(polish_time)
```

The output

```
2020-06-25 08:00:00-05:51
2020-06-25 15:51:00+02:00
```

While correct polish time should be 2020-06-25 15:00:00 (seven hour difference).
Can someone guide me on this? It's a bit puzzling to me and I can't understand why it is not working as I expected.

Comment: You're using `pytz` incorrectly, you need to use their `localize` function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11474330/5987

Comment: Thanks for quick and comprehensive answer!

Comment: You're far from the first person to run into this problem.  I think the designers of `datetime` expected `tzinfo` objects to be much more static than they are in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct a local time that way with pytz because timezones have changed throughout history. The particular offset for a particular timezone depends on the date in question. Building a timezone aware datetime like that doesn't run through that logic correctly and you end up with an incorrect offset.

For this reason, pytz provides `localize`. Use it like this:

```
chicago_time = chicago_timezone.localize(datetime.datetime(2020,6,25,8,0,0,0))
```

Comment: "*You can't construct a local time that way because timezones have changed throughout history*" - uh no, it's because `pytz` *handles* timezones like this

Comment: @MrFuppes `pytz` had no choice, because the `datetime` constructor doesn't give the `tzinfo` object an opportunity to update itself for the given date.

Comment: @MarkRansom that wasn't mean to *blame* pytz in any way ^^ Just wanted to point out that the *explanation* is misleading.

Comment: @MrFuppes no, the explanation is entirely correct based on my understanding.  Now one could question why `pytz` defaults to the earliest offset rather than the latest one, but that would only change the conditions when it's wrong not eliminate them.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I disagree. Time zones change throughout history. But that doesn't imply that one must use a scheme like pytz to handle them in combination with Python's datetime. It was implemented like this in pytz and that's fine *but* I doubt it couldn't have been done in any other way... The `dateutil` or `zoneinfo` modules show another way for example.

Comment: @MrFuppes I think the `tzinfo` interface has also changed over the years.  When `pytz` was written you weren't given the datetime it applied to when a member function like `utcoffset` was called, so you already had to know.  That's what `localize` does.  I was able to find an online 3.9 to play with `zoneinfo` and it appears to work correctly as well, but it never had to work with the more primitive interface.

Answer (score 0):

better use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) in the first place; no such issues here:

```
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9

chicago_timezone = ZoneInfo("America/Chicago")
warsaw_timezone = ZoneInfo("Europe/Warsaw")

chicago_time = datetime.datetime(2020,6,25,8,0,0,0, chicago_timezone)
print(chicago_time)
# 2020-06-25 08:00:00-05:00

warsaw_time = chicago_time.astimezone(warsaw_timezone )
print(warsaw_time)
# 2020-06-25 15:00:00+02:00
```

Comment: Note that it’s only available since 3.9…

Comment: @deceze yup, but that's been around for a while now.

Comment: @MrFuppes doesn't mean it's universally available.  I'm on Windows 7 and Python 3.9 is not and will never be supported there.

Comment: @MarkRansom well, the OP is a new user here and pytz is outdated from my perspective so I think it is worth an answer to suggest a more up-to-date way to handle time zones in Python. Btw. Windows 7 is also out of support ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes yes it's out of support, but it's still the best version of Windows ever made.