# timezones in python has couple of minutes shift

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

```
from pytz import timezone

import datetime
utc = datetime.timezone.utc

tz = timezone("Europe/London")
now = datetime.datetime.now(utc)
date = now.replace(tzinfo=tz)
date_utc = date.astimezone(utc)

print(now.isoformat())
print(date.isoformat())
print(date_utc.isoformat())
```

Might print:

```
2021-12-01T21:30:09.170108+00:00
2021-12-01T21:30:09.170108-00:01   <---- why does it say -00:01 here?
2021-12-01T21:31:09.170108+00:00
```

Why on earth is there a one minute shift?
Am I missing some fundamental knowledge on time zones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473721/weird-timezone-issue-with-pytz)

Comment: Note: with Python 3.9+, you have a standard lib module for this - [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63628816/10197418). Besides, no "localize trap" there. `replace` is safe to use with ZoneInfo timezone objects.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find this question and I was a little surprised no one every mentioned it. But somebody actually did, idk why I didn't stumble on it.

Ad 2nd comment: nice, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) from PYTZ

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.

You can only use `localize()` or `astimezone()` to attach PYTZ timezones to datetime objects

Comment: Yeah, I can see that it does not work :D what is a reason for that though?

Comment: It's just how `datetime` interprets it I believe