# Python - Add time zone to timestamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, python-3.1

I use chrome timestamp and convert it do readable date but time isn't right

```
timestamp_formated = str(datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=last_visit_time))
```

Seems to be timezone need to be added

example for last_visit_time : 13292010189305268

Comment: I somehow doubt that you are using a version of python that is EOL since 2012-04-09. And if you are, that your quesion is specific to that version.

Comment: And what does this have to do with google chorme???

Comment: What is a Chrome timestamp and why does it start in 1601?

Comment: I take timestamps from chrome-history file

Comment: 1601 to show the right year , try convert 13292010189305268 with the following function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Chrome timestamps denote microseconds since 1601 *UTC*, you'll want to make your `datetime` *aware*:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
timestamp = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=last_visit_time)
print(timestamp)
```

If you want to format it for a non-UTC timezone, add a conversion step:

```
local_timestamp = timestamp.astimezone(the_timezone)
```

Comment: How i can add gmt+ timezone ?

Comment: The result is 2022-03-25 06:54:06.554650+03:00 and i need it to be without the +03:00 it should be s 2022-03-25 09:54:06.554650

Comment: 6:54+03:00 would be 3:54 UTC. 6:54 UTC would be 9:54+03:00. Are you sure your expectation and conversion is correct?

Comment: Yes ( correct me if I'm wrong )  , I need the +3:00 to be implemented inside timestamp

Comment: i solved the issue with datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to localize(use timezone specific dates and time) you can use pytz for that

```
t = datetime(
2013, 5, 11, hour=11, minute=0,
tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')
```

)

Comment: that is ***not*** how you localize with `pytz` - see [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418).