# why do datetime.datetime and pendulum.datetime produce different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pytz, pendulum

Why `datetime` and `pendulum` produce different results in that code snippet? What am I missing?

```
from pytz import timezone
from pendulum import datetime as pendulum_datetime
from datetime import datetime as datetime_datetime

tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
# both `dt_pendulum` and `dt_dt` represent the same point in time: 2022, March 25, 10am (in US/Eastern)
dt_pendulum = pendulum_datetime(2022, 3, 25, 10, 0, tz=tz)
dt_dt = datetime_datetime(2022, 3, 25, 10, 0, tzinfo=tz)

# both datetimes are further converted to `US/Pacific`
# thus, they still represent the same point in time, just in different time zone.
dt_pendulum_pacific = dt_pendulum.astimezone(tz=timezone('US/Pacific'))
dt_dt_pacific = dt_dt.astimezone(tz=timezone('US/Pacific'))

print(dt_pendulum_pacific)
print(dt_dt_pacific)
```

produces:

```
2022-03-25T07:00:00-07:00
2022-03-25 07:56:00-07:00
```

I'm so confused by `07:56` thing returned by `datetime`. I thought `datetime.datetime` and `pendulum.datetime` should produce the same result in that example.

Comment: From the `pytz` documentation: *Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.*  It wasn't clear to me just what you're supposed to do instead.

Comment: @jasonharper, interesting. thanks. I found this in their doc as well: "The preferred way of dealing with times is to always work in UTC".

However to work with UTC, I need to convert time to UTC, if all I have is local time in `US/Eastern`. Seems to be a chicken egg problem.

Comment: the TLDR: that's ***not*** how you set a time zone with pytz: `datetime_datetime(2022, 3, 25, 10, 0, tzinfo=tz)`, instead, use `tz.localize(datetime_datetime(2022, 3, 25, 10, 0))`.

Comment: @FObersteiner, thanks for the pointer of the similar question. It answered my question. I'm still surprised to observe that behavior, as it feels error-prone given no warnings raised.

Comment: now that we have `zoneinfo` in the standard library, things should get better... but pytz is still ubiquitous - if you ever look for a [deprecations shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/), here it is.

Comment: I see. I think that could be an answer for python >= 3.9. If you write an answer to the original question (Weird timezone issue with pytz ...) I'll upvote it. Unfortunately can't test, as I'm using python 3.8

Comment: for Python 3.8, there's also [backports.zoneinfo](https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/), or you could use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which follows the same semantics as `zoneinfo`.

Comment: ok I've summarized my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668778/10197418) ;-)

Comment: detailed and helpful answer, thanks, upvoted! :)