# datetime tzinfo messes up datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime, pytz

It's a weird behavior I haven't seen before today. Somehow US Eastern timezone offset is 4 hours and 56 minutes from UTC. I've checked it on another machine and it is still the same.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(2021, 5, 5, 9, 30, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(dt)
# 2021-05-05 09:30:00-04:56
```

Comment: don't you just love the python datetime API
 - so well designed /s

Comment: see also: [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418)