# Convert EST Datetime to UTC Timestamp in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I'd like to know how to convert an EST Datetime string (e.g., '2020-02-02 09:30:00') to a UTC Timestamp with Python 3, without using external libraries such as pytz which gave me an inaccurate EST to UTC conversion.

Comment: Can you share the innacurate conversion pytz gave you?

Comment: you mean [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418)? I've added some more up-to-date options [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71668778/10197418)...

Comment: It was 6 minutes less than the accurate conversion.

Comment: Sounds like you did not `localize` and got LMT. Anyways, pytz is deprecated and you have zoneinfo, as below answer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting time zones has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563272/how-to-convert-a-utc-datetime-to-a-local-datetime-using-only-standard-library).

We just need [fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) for parsing.

The following will work with Python 3 from version 3.9 and up. If you're using Windows, make sure to run `pip install tzdata` to use `ZoneInfo`.

```
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
estDatetime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2020-02-02 09:30:00')
utcTimestamp = (
    date
    .replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    .astimezone(ZoneInfo('UTC'))
    .timestamp()
)
```

Comment: also note that neither `replace` nor `astimezone` work "in-place", i.e. you need to re-assign the returned value.

Comment: I'm receiving the error `zoneinfo._common.ZoneInfoNotFoundError: 'No time zone found with key America/New_York'`

Comment: @Lex are you on Windows? If so, make sure to install `tzdata`, see https://pypi.org/project/tzdata/

Comment: @FObersteiner Yes, that was the issue. Thanks!