# Start of day calculation using tz pytz timezone

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, pytz, tzinfo

We are interested in calculating a date using input fields that have month values and day values. For example the year_sent can be 2021, month_sent can be 0 and date_sent can be 31 for the date Jan 31st, 2021.

```
tz = pytz.timezone(obj_timezone)    
timestamp_current_tz_start_of_day   = datetime(year_sent, month_sent, date_sent, 0, 0, tzinfo=tz)

timestamp_current_start_of_day      = int((timestamp_current_tz_start_of_day - datetime(1970, 1, 1,0,0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)).total_seconds() * 1000)
```

We expect the timestamp_current_start_of_day to be Jan 31st, 2021 12:00am Timezone. But instead we get Jan 31st, 2021, 12:53am Timezone.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473721/weird-timezone-issue-with-pytz)

Comment: use `tz.localize(datetime(year_sent, month_sent, date_sent))`.