# Python - how to get equivalent local time during DST transition

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta, dst

```python
tz1 = pytz.timezone('UTC')
dt1 = tz1.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 25,0,38,43,454000))

tz2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt2 = tz2.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 25,1,38,43,454000))


print(dt1)
print(dt2)
print(dt1==dt2)
```

It returns:

```python
2020-10-25 00:38:43.454000+00:00
2020-10-25 01:38:43.454000+00:00
False
```

```python
tz1 = pytz.timezone('UTC')
dt1 = tz1.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 25,0,38,43,454000))

tz2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt2 = tz2.localize(datetime(2020, 10, 25,0,38,43,454000))


print(dt1)
print(dt2)
print(dt1==dt2)
```

returns:

```python
2020-10-25 00:38:43.454000+00:00
2020-10-25 00:38:43.454000+01:00
False
```

How can I make `dt1==dt2` return True while only adjusting `dt2`?

Note: 2020/10/25 is the day when DST ends in 2020.

Answer (score -2):

Let's talk about `dt1` and `dt2`, which are datetime objects. `dt1` is set to the **UTC** timezone, while `dt2` is set to the Europe/London timezone. Keep in mind that the Europe/London timezone follows daylight saving time (**DST**), so `dt2` is adjusted to consider the **DST** offset at that specific time.

Now, if you want `dt1` and `dt2` to be equal, you can modify `dt2` to match the local time during the **DST** transition. You can do this using the `is_dst` parameter of the `localize()` method.

Here's an example of code snippet for the possible resolution:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

# Set up time zones
tz1 = pytz.timezone('UTC')
tz2 = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

# Define the datetime in UTC
dt1 = datetime(2020, 10, 25, 0, 38, 43, 454000, tz1)

# Convert the datetime to the London timezone
dt2 = dt1.astimezone(tz2)

# Check if the two datetimes are equal
print(dt1)
print(dt2)
print(dt1 == dt2)
```

Output should be:

```
2020-10-25 00:38:43.454000+00:00
2020-10-25 01:38:43.454000+01:00
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code snippet but still got False. ```dt2``` is equal to ```2020-10-25 00:38:43.454000+01:00``` which is different from ```dt1```

Comment: I already edited the `code snippet`. Hope it works. This time, I got it and it prints `True`.

Comment: `datetime(2020, 10, 25, 0, 38, 43, 454000, tz1)` - that's **not** how you set a pytz timezone object. Use `localize`. Otherwise, you get the [weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418). Although direct placement in the datetime constructor works with UTC, it's better not to do so to avoid the ambiguity.