# Python UTC America/New York Time Conversion

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

Working on a problem where I have to evaluate whether a time stamp (UTC) exceeds 7PM `Americas/New_York`.

I naively did my check as:

```
if (timestamp - timedelta(hours=4)).time() > 19: 
    __logic__
```

Which obviously failed with daylight savings EST/EDT.

I think this works but feels wrong.

```
EST = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
biz_end = datetime(1990, 1, 1, 19, tzinfo=EST).astimezone(pytz.utc).hour

if timestamp.time() > biz_end: 
    __logic__
```

Is there a better solution here?

Comment: What python version you use?

Comment: Using python 3.10

Comment: you're setting the tz incorrectly btw., you must `localize` - see [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721/10197418). But, as @MarcinOrlowski says in the answer below, with Python 3.10, you should be using zoneinfo anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be far simpler to work directly in desired TZ rather than fighting time differences and DST as this would mostly add a headache for no other benefits:

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, time

# Get the UTC timestamp and convert to target TZ
timestamp_utc = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)  
timestamp_ny = timestamp_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))

if timestamp_ny.time() > time(19, 0):
    # It's past 7PM...
    pass
```

Also, if you use `pytz` only for this, you can use Python 3.9+ built-in libraries and drop `pytz` dependency, which as @FObersteiner linked in above comment, would also free you from [Weird timezone issue with pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11473721) problems:

```py
from datetime import datetime, time
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

timestamp_utc = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
timestamp_ny = timestamp_utc.astimezone(ZoneInfo('America/New_York'))

if timestamp_ny.time() > time(19, 0):
    pass
```