# pytz and astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a date and I need to make it time zone aware.

```
local_tz = timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
start_date = '2012-09-27'
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")   
start_date = start_date.astimezone(local_tz)


now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
local_now = now_utc.astimezone(local_tz)
```

I need to find if this is true:

```
print start_date>local_now
```

But I get this error.

```
   start_date = start_date.astimezone(local_tz)
   ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

I convert utc to tokyo with no issue.  I need to make start_date timezone aware ad well in tokyo.

Thanks

Comment: Since version 3.6, astimezone works with naive (timezone unawared) datetime. If you still working on lower version (<=3.5), timezone unawared datetime has to be awared by calling pytz.localize() .

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For `pytz` timezones, use their `.localize()` method to turn a naive `datetime` object into one with a timezone:

```
start_date = local_tz.localize(start_date)
```

For timezones without a DST transition, the [`.replace()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to attach a timezone to a naive `datetime` object should normally also work:

```
start_date = start_date.replace(tzinfo=local_tz)
```

See the [localized times and date arithmetic](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) of the pytz documentation for more details.

Comment: [pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) say that using tzinfo attribute directly fails for many timezones. tz.localize() should be used instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian for a good example of how badly it can fail see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442183/pytz-timezone-shows-weird-results-for-asia-calcutta and notice that it has nothing to do with DST.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Interesting. Updated the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I know. pytz uses 'Europe/Amsterdam' as an example of that.

Comment: Another WTF for python!

Comment: `start_date.replace(tzinfo=local_tz)` is wrong for any `local_tz` with a non-fixed utc offset (for any reason, not just DST e.g., Europe/Moscow has changed UTC offset recently). @Kevin: do you know a better datetime/timezone API in Python or any language (serious question: when I'd researched the question my conclusion was: "time zones are complicated". Your code may be also complicated or be simple and wrong (many people don't mind that the computer can't tell the correct time). The tz database (provided by pytz) is a good trade-off between the complexity and the correctness).

Answer (score 17):

You could use `local_tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)` to convert a naive datetime object to timezone-aware one.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

local_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')

start_date = local_tz.localize(datetime(2012, 9, 27), is_dst=None)
now_utc = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

print start_date > now_utc
```

`is_dst=None` forces .localize() to raise an exception if given local time is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django Rest Framework you could override the DateTimeField class like:

```
class DateTimeFieldOverridden(serializers.DateTimeField):

def to_representation(self, value):
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE)
    value = local_tz.localize(value)
    return super(DateTimeFieldOverridden, self).to_representation(value)
```

And you use it like this in your serializer:

```
date_time = DateTimeFieldOverridden(format='%d-%b-%Y', read_only=True)
```

Hope this helps someone.