# Get random timezone aware datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I am getting a random datetime between two datetimes with following code

```
start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC).toordinal()
end_date = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc).toordinal()
return datetime.date.fromordinal(random.randint(start_date, end_date))
```

The problem is that it is not timezone aware.

I have already tried making it timezone aware by using `tzinfo=pytz.UTC` as seen in the code above but it doesn't work. I guess `datetime.date.fromordinal()` makes it a naive datetime format.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626045/pytz-and-astimezone-cannot-be-applied-to-a-naive-datetime

Answer (score 2):

If you use `datetime.datetime` instead of `datetime.date` in your code then `.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)` works on the result.

To support arbitrary steps (not only `1 day`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

step = timedelta(days=1)
start = datetime(2013, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
end = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
random_date = start + random.randrange((end - start) // step + 1) * step
```

Note: if `start` uses a timezone with a non-fixed utc offset then call `tz.normalize()` at the end.