# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astimezone'

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python script:

```
import ftplib
import hashlib
import httplib
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
from pytz import timezone
import os.path, time
import glob

def ftphttp():
 files = glob.glob('Desktop/images/*.png')
 ts = map(os.path.getmtime, files)
 dts = map(datetime.fromtimestamp, ts)
 print ts

 timeZone= timezone('Asia/Singapore')
 #converting the timestamp in ISOdatetime format
 localtime = dts.astimezone(timeZone).isoformat()
```

I was trying to get the multiple files timestamp. I able to print out all the files in my folder

```
 [1467910949.379998, 1466578005.0, 1466528946.0]
```

But it also prompt me this error about the timezone. Anybody got any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
 ftphttp()
File "/home/kevin403/Testtimeloop.py", line 22, in ftphttp
 localtime = dts.astimezone(timeZone).isoformat()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'astimezone'
```

Comment: `dts` is a `list` (as returned by `map` here) and you are calling `astimezone` on it, which is a method it doesn't have.

Comment: not related but I would strongly recommend to use standard 4 space indents.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a method on a list of objects, instead of the objects in the list. Try calling the method on the first object instead:

```
localtime = dts[0].astimezone(timeZone).isoformat()
```

Or map over the list to get all timestamps in iso format:

```
localtimes = map(lambda x: x.astimezone(timeZone).isoformat(), dts)
```

Comment: I tried but i got this error: ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Comment: @AlvinWee that's another question, which seems to have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626045/pytz-and-astimezone-cannot-be-applied-to-a-naive-datetime

Answer (score 0):

`dts` is a list of time zones. So you need to do:

```
[ts.astimezone(timeZone) for ts in dts]
```

This will give you a list of the three time zones