# Why does datetime give different timezone formats for the same timezone?

Tags: python, python-datetime

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
>>> dt = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, now.microsecond, pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 16, 9, 24, 177751, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
>>> dt = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, now.microsecond, pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 16, 9, 24, 177751, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' LMT+9:19:00 STD>)
```

For `now` I got **JST+9:00:00** and for `dt` I got **LMT+9:19:00**. I don't understand why `datetime` uses a different format.

When I compare the times they are different:

```
>>> now == dt
False
```

How can I convert `LMT` to `JST` so that `now == dt` is `True`? I need to use `datetime(2018, 9, 7, 16, 9, 24, 177751, timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))` and at the same time I want `JST`.

Comment: What's JST and LMS?

Comment: Japan Standard Time && Local Mean Time

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626045/pytz-and-astimezone-cannot-be-applied-to-a-naive-datetime

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [a related question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390097/1247781), *Never create datetime with timezone info by using datetime()*. Instead, you should use `localize` to convert datetimes to JST after creating them in UTC.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
>>> dt = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute, now.second, now.microsecond, pytz.utc)
>>> jst = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
>>> jst.normalize(now)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 20, 21, 44, 653897, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
>>> jst.normalize(dt)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 7, 20, 21, 44, 653897, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
>>> now == dt
True
```