# convert naive time to time-zone aware time (JST)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a bunch of time objects stored in a database but they are all naive objects. The time they store is in 'JST' or 'Asia/Tokyo' tz. I tried using

`naive_time.replace(tzinfo = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))`

but this sets it to LMT+09:19:00 which is incorrect, it should be LMT+09:00:00. Any suggestions to do it rightly.

Edit:
The database returns the time as `datatime.time` object with `tzinfo=None` like `datetime.time(1, 0)`. I assigned this to t and tried

`t.replace(tzinfo = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))`

which gave

`datetime.time(1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' LMT+9:19:00 STD>)`

but 'Asia/Tokyo' or JST is 9 hours ahead of LMT not 9 hours 19 minutes.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you update your post to make your issue reproducible. At the moment we can only speculate on what happens. Please read [mcve] to get more insights about how to make your post meets SO Standards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does datetime give different timezone formats for the same timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217506/why-does-datetime-give-different-timezone-formats-for-the-same-timezone)

Comment: no it doesn't. I saw that answer earlier but it didn't help

Comment: the naive time object that i have stores value in this format `datetime.time(1, 0)` if i do `.replace(tzinfo = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))` then it returns `datetime.time(1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' LMT+9:19:00 STD>)` which is incorrect. the expected result should be `datetime.time(1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' LMT+9:00:00 STD>)`

Comment: Please could you post the complete code of your [mcve] (including imports and a datetime or time object as it is stored in your database).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to [add a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474670/pythonic-way-to-add-datetime-date-and-datetime-time-objects) so you can `localize` it. Otherwise the determination of DST is ambiguous: countries can choose if and when to use DST which lead to a lot of changes over time. See e.g. [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/japan) for `JST`. If you want to dig deep, check out the [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

***Example:***

```py
import datetime
import pytz

naive_time = datetime.time(1, 0)

date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 24)
comb_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date, naive_time)

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo')
loc_time = tz.localize(comb_time)

# loc_time
# datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)
```

You can find more info in Martijn Pieter's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13994611/10197418) why you should not use the `replace` method to set the timezone for naive `datetime` objects.

A general note which must not be missing in this context: always work with UTC internally if possible in any way - only determine local times for output to be read by humans.