# Getting astimezone error in linux machine

Tags: python, linux, pytz

I am using linux aws machine and there is a timezone difference when I do datetime.datetime.now. So I have tried this method to overcome the timezone error

```
format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
now_asia = current_date.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(now_asia.strftime(format))
```

when I do my window machine I didnt get any error. The same lines when I use in my linux machine I am getting "ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime"

To debug this I tried the methods which is mentioned in this link 
[pytz and astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626045/pytz-and-astimezone-cannot-be-applied-to-a-naive-datetime)

when I tried the first answer I am not getting any error but the timezone is not converted.
when I tried the second answer I am getting an error 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcnow'

I tried this

```
>>>loc_date = local_tz.localize(current_date)
>>> loc_date
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 7, 23, 36, 702645, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Kolkata' IST+5:30:00 STD>)
>>> loc_date.strftime(format)
'2020-04-06 07:23:36 IST+05:30'
```

I am getting this ,so according to indian time if we add 5:30 it will be correct. How should i do it.

Comment: Which Python version are you on?

Comment: I use python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you are indeed running the Python 3.7 interpreter in the cloud. Citing [the documentation for the `astimezone()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

> Changed in version 3.6: The astimezone() method **can now be called on naive instances that are *presumed to represent system local time***.

Indeed, I just tested the script using Python 3.5.9 and `pytz` 2019.3 and I get

```
  File "timez.py", line 6, in <module>
    now_asia = current_date.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

But when using Python 3.7.6 on an Amazon Linux 2 AMI instance, the code runs correctly.

Nevertheless, I would suggest to use timezone-aware datetimes from the start.

In [the code you're referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713155/2616577), you're getting that there's no `utcnow` attribute because that code imports `from datetime import datetime`, while you're doing `import datetime`. To make it work, you would use

```py
now_utc = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

But note that the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) now suggests you to use the `tz` parameter in `datetime.now`:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
local_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
now_asia = now_utc.astimezone(local_tz)

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
print(now_asia.strftime(format))
```

which prints `2020-04-22 09:25:21 IST+0530` in my case.