# Get new datetime object according to timezone difference

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7

Here is my code

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>from dateutil import tz
>>>current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Calcutta'))
>>>2013-05-12 17:11:36.362000+05:30
```

i don't want offset-aware i want to add time difference to my current time
so the time will be

```
>>>2013-05-12 22:41:36.362000
```

so that i will be able to get time difference from by simply.

```
>>> datetime.utcnow() - current_time
```

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to add in `>>>` before every line.

Comment: I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the offset with as a `datetime.timedelta` using:

```
offset = current_time.utcoffset()
```

The offset can then be added or subtracted from the current_time to obtain the desired datetime.

```
import datetime as DT
import dateutil.tz as tz
import dateutil

current_time = DT.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Calcutta'))
print(current_time)
# 2013-05-12 18:33:19.368122+05:30

offset = current_time.utcoffset()
naive_time = current_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
print(naive_time)
# 2013-05-12 18:33:19.368122
print(naive_time + offset)
# 2013-05-13 00:03:19.368122
```

Note that if you want the UTC time, you should *subtract* the offset:

```
print(naive_time - offset)
# 2013-05-12 13:03:19.368122
```

A simpler way to get the UTC datetime would be to use the `astimezone` method however:

```
utc = dateutil.tz.tzutc()
print(current_time.astimezone(utc))
# 2013-05-12 13:03:19.368122+00:00
```

Finally, note that using `dateutil` and `replace` to set the timezone [does not always return the correct time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944824/190597). Here is how you could do it with [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

```
import pytz
calcutta = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')
utc = pytz.utc
current_time = calcutta.localize(DT.datetime.utcnow())
print(current_time)
# 2013-05-12 18:33:19.368705+05:30
print(current_time.astimezone(utc))
# 2013-05-12 13:03:19.368705+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the offset by using `datetime.utcoffset()`

```
current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz.gettz('Asia/Calcutta'))
td = datetime.utcoffset(current_time)
#datetime.timedelta(0, 19800)
td.total_seconds() / 3600
#5.5
```