# Incorrect time zone conversion with datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python datetime object show wrong timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410971/python-datetime-object-show-wrong-timezone-offset)

I have a problem with conversion between timezones in Python, using the `pytz` library (last version 2012h). Here in Brussels we have normally UTC+1 hour in winter and UTC+2 hours in summer.

I have the following code :

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pytz

brussels_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')
utc_tz = pytz.utc

def main():
    intermdate = datetime(2012, 07, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0, brussels_tz)
    utcdate = intermdate.astimezone(utc_tz)
    print "Brussels time is %s" % intermdate
    print "UTC time is %s" % utcdate

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I get the following result :

```
Brussels time is 2012-07-15 08:00:00+00:00
UTC time is 2012-07-15 08:00:00+00:00
```

So no difference. In my opinion the result should be (in summer):

```
Brussels time is 2012-07-15 08:00:00+02:00
UTC time is 2012-07-15 06:00:00+00:00
```

If I use the timezone Europe/Paris (normally the same time as in Brussels) I get even more strange results:

```
Paris time is 2012-07-15 08:00:00+00:09
UTC time is 2012-07-15 07:51:00+00:00
```

A 9 minutes difference !?!

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the [`.localize()` method](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) to move a datetime into a timezone:

```
intermdate = brussels_tz.localize(datetime(2012, 07, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0))
utcdate = intermdate.astimezone(utc_tz)
```

The output is then:

```
Brussels time is 2012-07-15 08:00:00+02:00
UTC time is 2012-07-15 06:00:00+00:00
```

See the [`pytz` documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic):

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.
>
> ```
> >>> datetime(2002, 10, 27, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=amsterdam).strftime(fmt)
> '2002-10-27 12:00:00 AMT+0020'
> ```

Comment: Indeed it works :-) Thanks for fast reply Martijn.