# The newer pytz has minute for a timezone

Tags: pytz

Why did they add 6 more minutes to that? How can I make my own fix?

```
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.__version__
'2015.4'
>>> pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916418/pytz-timezoneasia-chongqing-is-behaving-strangely

Comment: @augurar Thank you. Exactly duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way:

```python
import pytz
import datetime

tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' CST+8:00:00 STD>)
```