# Date to datetime with timezone

Tags: python, datetime

How would I convert

"2022-02-01" to something like

"2022-02-01T()" there are no brackets I'd like to convert each 30 minute interval from 2022-02-01 00:30:00 H:M:S and so forth.

I wanted to use something like

```
startDates = [{'start': {'date': '2022-02-01'}}]  # Minimal Reproducible Example
timeZone = pytz.timezone('America/Vancouver')
for event in startDates:
    newStartDateTime = datetime.strptime(event['start']['date'], '%Y-%m-%d' )
    print(newStartDateTime)
    datetime_ist = datetime.strptime(event['start']['date'], '%Y-%m-%d' ).replace(tzinfo=timeZone)
    print("Date & Time in : ",datetime_ist.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

Which does produce a time slot at the first H:M:S I'd to obtain 48 of these

```
2022-02-01 00:00:00
Date & Time in :  2022-02-01T00:00:00-0812
```

Comment: How can a date of 1st Feb be 18th Feb in _any_ timezone? `datetime.now()` isn't producing that datetime converted to a different timezone; it's giving the current time in the specific timezone. Passing in your `datetime` object doesn't change that behaviour.

Comment: How would I add a timezone to that converted datetime. Must have missed taking out now. I used replace is that the correct method since I don't use datetime alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make your [datetime object timezone aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411149/1431750), using [`py.timezone.localize(datetime)`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/index.html?highlight=localize#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic). And then convert it using `astimezone()`.

For the 30-minute increments, use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to keep adding 30 mins to your `newStartDateTime`.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

vancouver_tz = pytz.timezone('America/Vancouver')
ist_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Calcutta')

startDates = [{'start': {'date': '2022-02-01'}}]  # Minimal Reproducible Example
for event in startDates:
    newStartDateTime = datetime.strptime(event['start']['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    vancouver_time = vancouver_tz.localize(newStartDateTime)
    india_time = vancouver_time.astimezone(tz=ist_tz)
    print("first Date & Time in IST:", india_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
    
    # now add increasing timedeltas in minute chunks
    for delta in range(0, 30 * 48, 30):
        offsetted_ist = india_time + timedelta(minutes=delta)
        print("Date & Time in IST:", offsetted_ist.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

Output:

```
first Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-01T13:30:00+0530
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-01T13:30:00+0530
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-01T14:00:00+0530
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-01T14:30:00+0530
...
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-02T12:00:00+0530
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-02T12:30:00+0530
Date & Time in IST: 2022-02-02T13:00:00+0530
```

Btw, choose if you want to use `camelCase` or `lowercase_with_underscores` for your variables. Pick *one*. Python is typically `lowercase_with_underscores`, except classes which are `UpperCamelCase`.

Comment: Sorry about the wait I was a bit busy it worked well didn't need the India time just the local.

Comment: I prefer camelCase  but due to the nature of how certain google api calendar works timeMin and also lowercase_with_underscores variables are prevalent so far.