# Why datetime doesn't give the expected result in Python?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have these datetime :

```py
    start = datetime(2023, 12, 10, 11, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
    stop = datetime(2023, 12, 10, 11, 1, 0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
```

Using "offset" instead of "time zone", these should correspond to :

`'2023-12-10T11:00:00+01:00'::timestamptz` for start and

`'2023-12-10T11:01:00+01:00'::timestamptz`for stop.

But when I try to use these datetimes in a PgSQL query (using psycopg2 driver), this is the transformation I get :

```py
                select = """
                    SELECT *
                    FROM my_table
                    WHERE code = %s
                    AND time >= %s
                    AND time < %s
                    ORDER BY time ASC
                """
                cursor.execute(select, (code, start, stop))
                print (cursor.query)
```

The printed query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE code = 'CODE1'
AND time >= '2023-12-10T11:00:00+00:09'::timestamptz
AND time < '2023-12-10T11:01:00+00:09'::timestamptz
ORDER BY time ASC
```

Where does this "+00:09" come from ? why is it not "+01:00" ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6410971/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: What do you get if you query `show timezone;` or `select current_setting('timezone',true);`? [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4J9TBAQo)

Comment: The take away is don't use `pytz`. For Python 3.9+ use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)